# ng-class and nested repeat slow

Tags: angularjs

The code below is OK fast in Crome but extremly slow in IE and Edge. Removing the ng-class improves about 100% in performance but still very slow. It seems to be both the nested loop and the ng-class. What can I do to improve performance here in IE and Edge? In Crome it takes around 3-4 seconds in Edge 40 seconds.

```
<tr ng-repeat="n in modelTurbineList">
    <td>{{n.TurbineType}}</td>
    <td>{{n.ParkName}}</td>
    <td>{{n.TurbineNumber}}</td>

    <td ng-repeat="x in n.Alarms track by $index" ng-class="{'alert-danger': x == 1, 'alert-success': x == 0, 'alert-warning': x == 2}"
        ng-click="openAlertLevelNav(x,n)">
        <div><a></a></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How much rows you're rendering, more than 1k or 2k?

Comment: 150 columns and 200 rows.

Comment: It means you have atleast (150*300) watchers on page. [More than 2000 watchers on the page slow down application performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/2435473)

Comment: Is the watches from the ng class or where do they come from? And what can I do? In crome it works perfectly.